# gcc error when writing string to char array

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

When attempting to assign a character string to the previously defined `char flightNumber[MAX]`, I'm hit with 
`error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror]` 
which is strange to me because I'm not using pointers, and I believe I am using the proper cast type, i.e. `char` not `int`. The issue is, the character string that is assigned to `flightNumber[MAX]` needs to change depending on what the user inputs for their choice above.

Relevant code from `main()` is pasted below

```
flightMenu();
scanf( "%d", &choice );
    while ( choice < 1 || choice > 3 ) {
        printf( "That is not a valid flight option!" );
        flightMenu();
        scanf( "%d", &choice );
    }

char name[MAX];
char flightNumber[MAX];

printf( "Enter your first name: ");
scanf( "%s", &name[MAX] );

if ( choice == 1 ) {
    flightNumber[MAX] = "MIA1050";
    seatReservation( flight1 );
}

else if ( choice == 2 ) {
    flightNumber[MAX] = "BNA1050";
    seatReservation( flight2 );
}
else if ( choice == 3 ) {
    flightNumber[MAX] = "LAS1050";
    seatReservation( flight3 );
}
```

Looks like other people have had similar issues, but I don't know how to use things like `strcpy` or pointers. Apologies for noob question and poor formatting, but nothing I do seems to fix the error, and my guess is I'm overlooking a really simple problem...

Comment: You need to use `strcpy` or `strncpy`. Assignment like you're doing it (using =) doesn't copy strings in C.

Comment: Would there be another way to do it other than `strcpy`? Unfortunately for this assignment, we are only permitted to use `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, and `time.h` C libraries.

Comment: Assigning to `flightNumber[MAX]` at all is writing out of bounds of the array.  It is also a `char`; you can't assign a string to a `char`.  You use `strcpy()` to 'assign' strings, and you start at the beginning, not one past the end, of the target array.

Comment: If you really have to copy these string literals (which I am not sure about), then you can roll your own version of strcpy, it's only one simple loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy a string you should use special function like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char source[1000], destination[1000];

   printf("Input a string\n");
   gets(source);

   strcpy(destination, source);

   printf("Source string:      \"%s\"\n", source);
   printf("Destination string: \"%s\"\n", destination);

   return 0;
}
```

http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-copy-strings

Comment: Now this is a good example for a buffer overflow that can be triggered by users, never write such code in a real program

Answer (score 0):

The C library function

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
```

copies the string pointed by src to dest.

So use that instead of flightNumber[MAX] = "anything ";

One more detail: the strcpy() function is defined in string.h header file.

Answer (score 0):

flightNumber[MAX] is an array of chars. (a local buffer on the stack with size MAX), whereas the three flight numbers you attempt to assign are string literals.

A string literal evaluates to a char pointer in order to assign it. (char*)

Therefore, you have to use char pointers instead of this array to assign the literals.

However, if you really want to copy a string literal to a mutable buffer, then you can use strncpy().

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have given you good options for how to copy strings, but to answer the question about why you get the error `error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror]`:

`char flightNumber[MAX];` is a declaration of the char array, but the statement `flightNumber[MAX] = "MIA1050";` means "assign `"MIA1050"` to the element at index `MAX` in `flightnumber`".

That is wrong for two different reasons:

1. You are trying to assign a string literal to a character variable (the elements of `flightNumber` are `char`s. This is the type mismatch the compiler complains about: the type of a string literal is `const char*`, and you are assigning that to a variable of type `char`, hence implicitly converting a pointer to an integer type (`char`).
2. It is out-of-bounds: the largest index in `flightNumber` is `MAX-1` since the indices of C arrays start at zero.

To use the array, just use its name (i.e., `flightNumber`) and not the name+size as in the declaration (i.e., `flightNumber[MAX]`).
Now, as the other answers point out, the assignment `flightNumber = "MIA1050"` would not do what you want, so you need to use for instance `strncpy`.

By the way, please prefer `strncpy` (which takes a length argument) to the less safe `strcpy` as the default to reduce the risk of buffer overflows.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about C array indexing, I should have caught that myself. I'll look into `strncpy`, but out of curiosity, will it work for user-defined string inputs, such as in `char name[MAX]`?

Comment: @Likasumboode, yes, `strcpy(char* dest, const char *src)` simply copies a null-terminating string starting at `src` into the memory pointed to by `dest`. As long as the array pointed to by `dest` is big enough (and not `const`) it works for any `char[]`. As for `strncpy`, it works the same, but copies at most `n` characters. One thing you need to look out for is that if `strlen(src) > n`, the string pointed to by `dest` will not be null terminated.  To check the string length of `src` you can use `strnlen()`

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `flightnumber[MAX] = "MIA1050";`, as an example, attempts to assign the memory address of the text string `"MIA1050"` (rather than the characters in the string itself) to the `MAX`-th element location in the `flightnumber` array (since array numbering starts from 0, this would also be past the end of the array as the final element in the array is at index `MAX-1`). Since the array is of `char`s, which are an integer type (not to be confused with `int`, which is also an integer type although typically of a different size), this is also an attempt to assign a memory address to a location that is marked as containing an integer type, which the compiler treats as the error that you see.

To resolve the error and achieve the functionality of 'assigning the string' to a storage location, the two main approaches are to copy the actual string characters into a buffer or pass the addresses of the string literals around (both of which the above answers to your question have made note of). For the former, standard library tools such as `strcpy` are generally effective solutions to copy a string of characters from one location (such as a string literal's location) to another (such as a buffer like `flightnumber` in your example). For the latter approach, you could create a variable of type `char *` rather than a `char` array, in which case you could assign the string literal to that variable, as the attempt to assign the address of the characters would then be correct as the variable would be of the right type (pointer-to-`char`).

Which approach is preferable depends on the particular application and what is being done with the string literal. However, if the only thing being done with the string is to print out the resulting value or something along those lines the second approach (that of storing the address pointing to the literal rather than copying the actual characters) might be preferable as assigning a single address is generally going to be less expensive performance- and memory-storage- wise than creating a buffer and performing a copy of a region of memory (not that the difference would really be significant unless the program performs this same task a great many times).

I also second the suggestion that you put some focus into understanding at least the basics of pointer management in C before proceeding too much further as it is very fundamental to effectively using the language. Some attention to the layout of C-style character strings would also probably be a good idea.